# Large composed plots in a single subplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

**Introduction**

I am currently working on a MATLAB script which handles a large plot rutine. In short I am creating a plot that consist of several other plots. Now I want this plot into a subplot with another plot. However, I cannot seem to get this working.

**Code:**

My first plot:

```
h = figure('Units', 'pixels', ...
'Position', [100 100 1000 375]);
= fill([xfit fliplr(xfit)],[meanSeq-stdSeq fliplr(meanSeq+stdSeq)],[0.7 0.7
0.7],'linestyle','none');
b = fill([xfit fliplr(xfit)],[meanMul-stdMul fliplr(meanMul+stdMul)],[0.7 0.7 0.7],'linestyle','none');
c = plot(xfit,meanSeq,'black','linewidth',1.5); %% change color or linewidth to adjust mean line
e = plot(xfit,meanSeq./7.5,'color',[0.75 0 0],'linewidth',1.5);
d = plot(xfit,meanMul,'b','linewidth',1.5); %% change color or linewidth to adjust mean line
axis([0 max(xfit) 0 max(meanSeq)+10]);
subplot(2,1,1);
```

and my second plot:

```
hTwo = figure('Units', 'pixels', ...
'Position', [100 100 1000 375]);
f = plot(xfit,meanSeq./meanMul,'linewidth',1.5);
hold on

g = plot(xfit,1/(0.01+0.99/8),'linewidth',1.5);
hij = plot(xfit,mean(meanSeq./meanMul),'linewidth',1.5);
axis([0 max(xfit) 5 8]);
subplot(2,1,2);
```

**Question**
Now, apperantly it is not possible to put these two separte plots into one subplot all I get is an empty white graph. Each plot rutine works seperatly.

Comment: Can you provide a minimalist example that shows this behaviour, so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: I guess that you missed `a =` in the first line after the definition of h. I cannot edit because is too few characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the subplot(2,1,1) before you plot with plot().
As I'm not able to run your code I give you the general plan:

1- figure()

2- subplot(2,1,1)

3- plot() % plot data into first subplot

4- subplot(2,1,2)

5- plot() % plot data into second subplot